# avoid outputs overlap each other

Tags: javascript

Javascript

```
function moveDiv() {
    var $span = $("#random");

    $span.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        var maxLeft = $(window).width() - $span.width();
        var maxTop = $(window).height() - $span.height();
        var leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLeft + 1))
        var topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTop + 1))

        $span.css({ left: leftPos, top: topPos }).fadeIn(1000);
    });
};

moveDiv();
setInterval(moveDiv, 5000);
function moveDiv1() {
    var $span = $("#random1");

    $span.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        var maxLeft = $(window).width() - $span.width();
        var maxTop = $(window).height() - $span.height();
        var leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLeft + 1))
        var topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTop + 1))

        $span.css({ left: leftPos, top: topPos }).fadeIn(1000);
    });
};

moveDiv1();
setInterval(moveDiv1, 5000);
```

Sometimes ,the two outputs will overlap each other , how to avoid them overlap each other?

Do I need a collision detection on them?

Comment: seems to work just fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/s86k42r8/

Comment: @blewherself you need add position:absolute to make outputs random move

Comment: Then yeah, you'd need some kind of collision detectio. Try to check this example https://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/TG2M7/